# updating component doesnot show any effect in vue file when browser is refreshed.project is in cpanel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My project is build in laravel framework with vuejs. My problem is that when I update component and refresh the browser no change is shown. It is working fine in local. This problem shows up when project is uploaded to cpanel. What could be the reason? Even if i empty the component then still the component is seen as before, nothing changes.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When you make a project with laravel and Vue.js, you need to use a command in cmd/terminal
`npm run watch`, when this command is runs your vue scripts automatically building with webpack, and then displaying in browser window. 
When you want to upload your project and make it in production version, you need to run `npm run build` to build your components. If you able to run npm command on your hosting provider try to run `npm run build` in your project folder on the server, after that the changes can be see immediately. If not run it locally and upload to server.

PS. Please provide more information.